# Is there a way to find out who is buying or selling off large volume of stocks?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, selling, money-market

Is there a  way to find out who is buying or selling off large volume  of stocks?

Is there a software/web program for this?

Answer (score 2):

The SEC requires that [Large Traders](https://www.sec.gov/rules/final/2011/34-64976.pdf)  report trades to  the SEC  on Form 13H.  A large trader is defined  as someone who  transacts:

- 2 million or more shares or $20 million in a NMS security during any one day
- 20 million shares or $200 million during any calendar month.

The SEC also [requires](https://www.sec.gov/smallbusiness/goingpublic/officersanddirectors)  that

- "shareholders who acquire more than 5% of the outstanding shares of that class must file beneficial owner reports on Schedule 13D or 13G until their holdings drop below 5%."
- "Section 16 of the Exchange Act applies to an SEC reporting company's directors and officers, as well as shareholders who own more than 10% of a class of the company's equity securities registered under the Exchange Act."

Other than SEC requirements, there is no public disclosure of who trades what each day.